# jQuery Search Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i'm building a project which has a page navigation and search bar in jQuery.

I can't get my search function to work correctly and I'm not certain if it's a problem with the ID element or the each function.  I'm getting the ("Sorry, no student's found!") message for anything that is or isn't a match. So i think there could be a problem with the if statement looking for a match in search function--but not sure.

I'm dynamically adding a search box to my html like this:

```
function appendSearchBox(){
    var search = "<div class='student-search'><input id='search' placeholder='Search for students...'><button>Search</button></div>"
    $(".students").after(search);

    // Add click event handler
    $("button").click(function() {
        searchList();
    });

}
```

this is what my html looks like for a list of students:

```
  <div class="page">
      <div class="page-header cf">
        <h2 class="students">Students</h2>

      </div>
      <ul class="student-list">
        <li class="student-item cf">
            <div class="student-details">
                <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
                <h3>iboya vat</h3>
                <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
            </div>
            <div class="joined-details">
                   <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
           </div>
        </li>
</ul>
```

And then here is the actual search function:

```
var listStudents = $(".student-list li");
var numStudents = listStudents.length;

function searchList() {
    var matched = [];
    // Obtain the value of the search input
    input = $("#search").val()
    // remove the previous page link section
    $('.pagination').hide();
    // Loop over the student list, and for each student…
    listStudents.each(function(){
        // ...obtain the student’s name…
        var name = $(this).find("h3").val();
        // ...and the student’s email…
        var email = $(this).find(".email").val();
        // ...if the search value is found inside either email or name…
        if (name.includes(input) || email.includes(input))  {
             // ...add this student to list of “matched” student
             matched.push($(this).parent());
             }
     });
     // If there’s no “matched” students…
     if (matched.length === 0){
         // ...display a “no student’s found” message
            var message = ("Sorry, no student's found!");
            $(".student-list").hide();
            $(".student-list").after(message);

     if (matched.length > 10) {
        // ...call appendPageLinks with the matched students
        appendPageLinks(matched);
        }
        // Call showPage to show first ten students of matched list
        showPage(1, matched);
     }


}
```

adding functions which actually show the students and add navigation

```
function showPage(pageNum, listStudents) {
    // first hide all students on the page
    pageNum = parseInt(pageNum);
    listStudents.hide();
    // Then loop through all students in our student list argument
    listStudents.each(function(index){
    // if student should be on this page number
        if ((index >= ((pageNum*10)-9)) &&  (index <= (pageNum*10))) {
        // show the student
            $(this).show();
            }
    });

 }

function getNumPages(numStudents){
    numPages = Math.ceil(numStudents/10);
    return numPages;
    }


function appendPageLinks(numStudents) {
    // determine how many pages for this student list
    pages  = getNumPages(numStudents);
    // create a page link section
    var nav = "<div class='pagination'><ul>"
    for (i=1; i<pages+1; i+=1){
        nav += ("<li>" + "<a href='#' id=" + i + ">" + i + "</a>" + "</li>");
    };
    nav += ("</ul></div>");
    $(".student-list").after(nav);

    // define what happens when you click a link
    var active = $('.pagination a').click(function(){
        // Use the showPage function to display the page for the link clicked
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        showPage(id,listStudents);
        // mark that link as “active”
        active.removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass("active");
        });
}
```

here is how i am calling the functions:

```
appendSearchBox();
showPage(1, listStudents);
appendPageLinks(numStudents);
```

UPDATE -- I have changed the code to remove the val and put in to grab the text.

Not sure what issue is but it appears if i have a correct match--it is working (since pagination disappears) but the students do not change on the page.  If there is no match then I get the error message, but the error console is saying

```
Uncaught TypeError: listStudents.hide is not a function
    at showPage (main.js:8)
```

I'm not sure if this is somehow related to how I am passing the 'matched' list?

Comment: It should work... maybe it's a problem about casing? perhaps you should modify the `includes` as uppercase. `if (name.toUpperCase().includes(input.toUpperCase()) || email.toUpperCase().includes(input.toUpperCase())) `

Comment: The `listStudents` parameter in `showPage` method is an array (matched array). To hide all the students use `$(".student-list li").hide();` instead of `listStudents.hide();`

Comment: when i do that --still no matches appearing (with no errors)- but a bad search provides a new error listStudents.each is not a function

Answer (score 0):

`h3` and `span` tags have no value, but text content, so replace:

```
    var name = $(this).find("h3").val();
    // ...and the student’s email…
    var email = $(this).find(".email").val();
```

with:

```
    var name = $(this).find("h3").text();
    // ...and the student’s email…
    var email = $(this).find(".email").text();
```

Comment: hi thanks --definitely right on that one--but for some reason the page isn't showing the correct matches.  i updated my post--please have a gander if you get a free moment.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are using `val()` method to read inner text of h3 and span (email). It should be `text()`. Also you are appending message after the student list every time you couldn't find a student. You could have used one `span` tag and hide/show based on the search results.

```js
function appendSearchBox() {
 var search = "<div class='student-search'><input id='search' placeholder='Search for students...'><button>Search</button></div>"
 $(".students").after(search);

 // Add click event handler
 $("button").click(function () {
  searchList();
 });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
 appendSearchBox();
});

function searchList() {
 var listStudents = $(".student-list li");
 var numStudents = listStudents.length;
 $(".student-list").show();
 $("#message").hide();

 var matched = [];
 // Obtain the value of the search input
 input = $("#search").val()
 // remove the previous page link section
 $('.pagination').hide();

 // Loop over the student list, and for each student…
 listStudents.each(function () {
  // ...obtain the student’s name…
  var name = $(this).find("h3").text();
  // ...and the student’s email…
  var email = $(this).find(".email").text();
  // ...if the search value is found inside either email or name…
  if (name.includes(input) || email.includes(input)) {
   // ...add this student to list of “matched” student
   matched.push($(this).parent());
  }
 });
 // If there’s no “matched” students…
 if (matched.length === 0) {
  // ...display a “no student’s found” message
  var message = ("Sorry, no student's found!");
  $(".student-list").hide();
  $("#message").show();

  if (matched.length > 10) {
   // ...call appendPageLinks with the matched students
   appendPageLinks(matched);
  }
  // Call showPage to show first ten students of matched list
  showPage(1, matched);
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="page">
 <div class="page-header cf">
  <h2 class="students">Students</h2>
 </div>

 <ul class="student-list">
  <li class="student-item cf">
   <div class="student-details">
    <img class="avatar" src="https://randomuser.me/api/portraits/thumb/women/67.jpg">
    <h3>iboya vat</h3>
    <span class="email">iboya.vat@example.com</span>
   </div>
   <div class="joined-details">
    <span class="date">Joined 07/15/15</span>
   </div>
  </li>
 </ul>

 <span id="message" style="display:none;"><br/>Sorry, no student's found!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: hi phani--thanks for comments--- i think you are right about getting the text values.  I'm having some other issues--did update the code--feel free to have a look when you get a sec.